# Is it possible to ignore or prevent window from minimizing after window shake gesture

Tags: winapi

I have a regular window which is WS_EX_TOPMOST style and expected always to be shown, but shake gesture minimizes it. Is there a way to handle this gesture?

Comment: I don't believe that you can disable aeroshake. Maybe you could have an event handler listen for the minimize event and get back on top when it happens?

Comment: @JakobLovern I handle WM_SYSCOMMAND - SC_MINIMIZE but it does not work

Comment: A Windows user can disable the Aero Shake feature on his or her system.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand yeh, i know but it's not the case

Comment: You are missing the point. This is a user setting. It's not something an application should override. If a user doesn't like Aero Shake, they can turn it off.

Answer (score 0):

Without judgement on whether or not you should do it (I kinda agree with @IInspectable), you can handle `WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING` message like that to prevent changes:

```
case WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING:
    ((WINDOWPOS*)lParam)->flags |= SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOMOVE;
    break;
```